# Retrying a Async_task and NSURLConnection in case of failure

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, httprequest, grand-central-dispatch

Inside the `dispatch_async` I am making a http request to the server, now in case the request fails I need to retry the last request, but since this being a asynchronous request, is it possible to restart the `async_task` itself?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
          ^{
              [[LocUtility sharedInstance] CallDelayApiwithLocation:newLocation];
          });
```

Or please kindly suggest any methods for doing these kind of request in case of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the NSTimer class.  When your request fails, you can create an NSTimer that will fire repeatedly at stated intervals.  Invalidate the timer when your request succeeds.  Remember to handle things in the case of the app going to the background and returning.

Comment: Hai when i do this while the app is in background, timers wouldn't be available for me, in that case how can i do that??

Comment: When you're in the background, there's nothing you can do anyway. Wait until you reappear in the foreground and restart the timer.

Comment: @OwenHartnett I beg to differ ;) background fetch with ios7+!?

Comment: iOS 7 wasn't out when I wrote that - see http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html for details.